# Which ports should be open for Facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I tried to improve my server security by setting up some iptables firewall rules. The result is that Facebook login with Omniauth stopped working. In my logs I see that Facebook is sending some packages to my server ports 37035 and 41198 at least. Why? There is nothing running in those ports.

Can someone say which ports I should open so that Facebook login with Omniauth could start working again on my site.

The rules I applied are:

```
# Delete all existing rules
iptables -X

# Set default rules
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Allow ssh in
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming HTTP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing SSH
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow ping from outside
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

# Allow pingging other servers
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback access
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow sendmail and postfix
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow dns lookups
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

# Prevent dos attacks - upgrade to hashlimit if needed
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT

# Log dropped packages
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

Here is an example log entry from my syslog (My IP is filtered)

```
IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=40:40:ea:31:ac:8d:64:00:f1:cd:1f:7f:08:00 SRC=69.171.224.54 DST=my_ip LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=86 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=44605 WINDOW=14480 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
```

Comment: I see the same kind of traffic. Different port however. `api-read-slb-10-08-prn1.facebook.com`

Comment: It looks to me that the requests are coming to random ports between 30000 and 60000. Allowing traffic for that range fixed Facebook login partially. It works but is much slower than when all the ports are open.

Comment: This same issue can be seen with Google login as well. I have added Google strategy for my application as well. This makes me suspect that the issue is originated from Omniauth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got an answer for this question. https://superuser.com/questions/479503/why-are-ports-30000-to-60000-needed-when-browsing-the-net

Ports from 32768 to 61000 are needed for http connections.